# Problems with javascript after installing SSL

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ssl

I have installed a SSL certificate in my website (it uses Wordpress) and I have got incompatibilities with the javascript. I am using plugins **Cookie law info** and **Lightbox**, which are not working anymore. I also use my own basic JS code and it is not working neither. What may happen?

After the SSL installation, I did the following:

- change the wordpress Address (URL) for the new one with https
- add the following code in the .htaccess file:

  RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ipd2004.com/$1 [R,L]
- add these two lines in the wp-config.php file:

  ```
  define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
  define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
  ```

I hope you can help me fixing this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will typically refuse to load HTTP assets like images, CSS, JS on a HTTPS page (called ["mixed content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent)). Ensure that your JavaScript libraries (including anything they rely on, like jQuery) are loaded via HTTPS too.

This'll be visible in your browser's web developer console.

Comment: That is right! I thought URLs from external domains should not be changed. Now it seems most of the issues are gone.